# custom svelte store with immer is refreshing while data is same, also data binding is not working

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, immer.js, svelte-store

The issue with this code is that the store triggering its subscribers but the data has not changed. The button is simply setting `sub.a=10`. However the store is refreshing which is not supposed to. Immerjs is supposed to help with this.
Also the data binding is not working and this is related to the `set` and probably `update` methods on the custom store. How could I achieve these functionalities?

This is the custom store:

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import produce from "immer";

const immerWritable = (value) => {
  const store = writable(value);

  function set(new_value) {
    if (new_value !== value) {
      store.set((value = new_value));
    }
  }

  const producer = (fuc) => store.update((state) => produce(state, fuc));

  return {
    producer,
    set,
    update: (fn) => set(produce(value, fn)),
    subscribe: store.subscribe
  };
};

const store = immerWritable({
  sub: { a: 1, b: 2 },
  sub2: { a: 1, b: 2 }
});

const actions = {
  setSubA_10: () =>
    store.producer((draft) => {
      draft.sub.a = 10;
    })
};

export default { ...store, ...actions };
```

the app.svelte

```html
<svelte:options immutable={true} />
<script>
  import Changed from "./Changed.svelte";
  import store from "./store";
  import { onDestroy } from "svelte";
  let changed = 0;
  const sub = store.subscribe(s => {
    changed++;
  });
  onDestroy(sub);
</script>




<div>store changed {changed} </div>
<button on:click={store.setSubA_10} >set sub.a to 10</button>
<input bind:value={$store.sub.a} type="number"/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-playground-forked-t21xfi?file=/App.svelte:0-412

Comment: "Immerjs is supposed to help with this" - Why would that help? That is just how stores and invalidation work in Svelte.

Comment: @H.B. sometimes you have a store that very nested and is connected to network requests and that is where things go crazy. Checkout my answer. `valtio` can help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `valtio` could help in creating a store that does not trigger a refresh if data is the same.

Here is the store file:

```js
import { snapshot, subscribe, proxy, } from "valtio"
import { derive } from 'valtio/utils'



export const proxyToReadable = (proxyState: any) => ({
  subscribe(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    fn(snapshot(proxyState))
    return subscribe(proxyState, () => fn(snapshot(proxyState)))
  }
})


const proxyStore = proxy({
  sub1: { a: 1, b: 2 },
  sub2: { c: 3, d: 4 },
})

//you can add derived reactive properties
derive({
  onlyC: (get): number => get(proxyStore).sub2.c,
},
  {
    proxy: proxyStore,
  })


//to be attached as an action. it only changes the value once. any further calls will never trigger a refresh.
const inc = () => proxyStore.sub2.c = 1

//the final assembly
//note that you need to export the proxy as well if intent to edit/bind the data without relying on pre-defined action functions like `inc`.
export default { ...proxyToReadable(proxyStore), inc, proxy: proxyStore }
```

```html
<script>
  import store,{proxyToReadable} from "./store";

  //you can subscribe to a sub data, if sub2 change, this sub1 will not trigger
  const sub1 = proxyToReadable(store.proxy.sub1)
  $: console.log("store",$store)
  $:console.log("store",$sub1)
</script>

<button on:click={() => store.inc()}>inc</button>
<input type="text" bind:value={store.proxy.sub1.b} />
```